# Setting foldmethod=manual when viewing Vim help buffer

Tags: vim

I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
foldmethod=indent
au FileType help setlocal foldmethod=manual
```

But when I open Vim help, e.g. `:h foldmethod` then `:set foldmethod?` still returns indent.

Comment: Try this instead, `NL` means new line: `augroup filetype_help` NL `autocmd!` NL `autocmd FileType help setlocal foldmethod=manual` NL `augroup END`

Comment: I think you mean `set foldmethod=indent`. Anyway it works fine on my end.

Comment: Oops, yes I meant `setlocal foldmethod=indent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `FileType` did not work, but using `BufReadPre` and `buftype` did. Here's is the relevant code:

```
au BufReadPre * if (&buftype == 'help') | setlocal foldmethod=manual | endif
```

Comment: Glad you found the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `'foldmethod'` may have been set by a modeline. Check whether the help file contains a line like this:

```
vim:tw=78:ts=8:ft=help:fdm=indent:
```

To investigate, you can also use the command

```
:verbose setlocal foldmethod?
```

If it says `Last set from modeline`, you'd need to remove the setting from there, because modelines always overrule autocmds.

Comment: Good tip. But there is no modeline with `fdm` set in the help files that I see this issue in. I posted a solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to put this in an answer, so that I can format it:

```
augroup filetype_help
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType help setlocal foldmethod=manual
augroup END
```

Hope this works. :)

Comment: Oh BTW, if it works, please give this question a like, and accept it as an answer. ;)

Comment: This just adds an `augroup` but isn't different from the OP otherwise.

Comment: Well it works for me, in other things, maybe it's different. :)

Comment: BTW, this is the method I use for file type specific stuff, and it works fine, so it's probably something on your end.